# Are there any good tar compression algorithms for huge directories (1 - 10TB) of random content?

Tags: compression, tar

I want to backup and compress all of my data on my Linux PC. The size of all this files adds up to about 3.4 TB. I want to compress them with tar and some compression algorithm.

I already tried some algorithms like xz but they only yielded a marginal 10% of compression (lost between 100 to 300 gigs).

Are there any algorithms which yield 20% to 40% of compression for such huge amounts of data? Neither RAM nor processing power are a concern for me in regards of the algorithm (32 gigs of ram and a 4790k).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xz is already a very good compressor. It seems that your data is simply not very compressible. There is no magic compressor that will do two to four times better. You might get a little gain from a PPM-based compressor, maybe, but much.

Your only hope would be to perhaps recognize compression already applied to your data, decompress it, and then recompress it with something better than the original compressor.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I'm going to check out the PPM based compressors.